# Overlaying other objects in Flash full screen video

Tags: flash, google-maps

Is there a way to overlay other objects on top of fullscreen video in Flash Player?

i want to put a googlemap over a 'full screen' flash video player, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends how you are running fullscreen video. I know that you can just tell the FLVplayback to go fullscreen and this mean that only the video is shown and nothing else that was around it.

You can also specify a rectangular region that you would like fullscreen that includes your video. If you are looking at adding other elements besides the video this may be an option.

Have you tried adding a display object to the one that contains your video?

Here is some (a bit old) info on using the rectangle region in AS2 and AS3.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/full_screen_mode_02.html